# How long must one wait before re-parking in the same time-limited parking spot in Seattle?

Tags: united-states, driving, washington, parking

Many parking spots in Seattle are time-limited, e.g. 2 hours:

[image: IMG:]

How long must one wait before re-parking in the such time-limited parking spots in Seattle (Washington state, United States)?

Answer (score 7):

According to [11.72.240 of the Seattle Municipal Code](https://library.municode.com/wa/seattle/codes/municipal_code?nodeId=TIT11VETR_SUBTITLE_ITRCO_PT7STSTPALO_CH11.72STSTPARE_11.72.220TENOPAZO), entitled *Moving vehicle to avoid time limit*:

> No person shall move and repark a vehicle on either side of a street within the same block in order to avoid a parking time limit regulation specified for either side of the street in that particular block.

Comment: Thanks! How long must one wait before re-parking in the same time-limited parking spot in Seattle?

Comment: To me it reads like 8am the next day, but I'll have a dig around the Code and report back if I find anything relevant

Comment: @RockApe actually you could re-park at 6pm when the restriction ends.

Comment: @DaleM ah, good spot. I'm kicking myself for missing that :) But would it still be a "time-limited" spot once the restrictions end (rhetorical)? Sounds a bit metaphysical to me so is probably off-topic and more suited to PhilosophySE (rhetorical - again)

Comment: @RockApe couldn’t say about Seattle but where I’m from the time limit applies to all the restrictions on the sign. Unless there’s another sign.

Comment: If you read the cited section literally, you could drive off for a say half an hour for a purpose other than to avoid the time limit, then park on the other side. That's assuming there is nothing else prohibiting it. You might want to add 17.12.260 is the code preventing you from parking too long.

Comment: @abligh but how do they check that you just didnt repark though? In my country you "just" have to drive away literally and re-park, so others have a chance to get the spot kinda. They check your tire caps and write down the positions, if not moved or just slightly you get a ticket.

Comment: @bibleblade I have no idea. I am just reading the statute.